# Como criar um MesageBox listando dados em c#?

Tags: c#

Pretendo criar uma notificação, usando o messagebox, de modo a listar todos produtos  cadastrado no sistema com quantidade minima assim que executo o sistema.

Comment: O MessageBox é usado para mensagens de informação, avisos e erros porque ela normalmente trava o usuário até que ele feche a janela com a mensagem. Além disso você não tem recursos de formatação nessa janela para colocar dados complexos. Melhor abordagem seria criar um formulário específico para apresentar esses dados e o MessageBox apenas para colocar algo como "Relatório XYZ disponível. Deseja abrir agora?"

Comment: Lendo melhor a pergunta, acho que não esteja obrigando que seja MessageBox. Uma dúvida, você está usando Forms ou WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

este é a class:

```
 class Lista_de_produto
 {
    public string Nome_produto { get; set; } 
    public int qtd  { get; set; } 

   public List<Lista_de_produto> GetAll()
   {
       List<Lista_de_produto> g=new List<Lista_de_produto>();

      //faça aqui o teu select, sem utilizar o where

       return g;
   }

 }
```

Aqui é no form

```
string Mensagem="";
int qtd_min=5; 
Lista_de_produto tg=new Lista_de_produto();
List<Lista_de_produto> List=tg.GetAll() ;  
List<Lista_de_produto> ver=List.FindAll(X => X.qtd <= qtd_min);

if(ver.Count>0)
{
    for(int a=0;a<=ver.Count;a++)
    {
      Mensagem=Mensagem+ver[a].Nome_produto +"\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Mensagem);
 }
```

Comment: Já fiz algo do gênero e não resultou